# When to use raw (not relative) change vs. absolute change in a T-Test?

Tags: t-test, paired-data, differences

Suppose I have students 1 through 100 predict their test scores prior to taking a test. After the test, I record their actual scores, so that the head of my data table looks like this:

```
   Student AnticipatedScore ActualScore Change AbsoluteChange
1       1                 9          10      1              1
2       2                10           9     -1              1
3       3                 6           6      0              0
4       4                 7           9      2              2
5       5                 5           3     -2              2
6       6                 2           3      1              1
7       7                 5           4     -1              1
8       8                10          10      0              0
9       9                 8          10      2              2
10     10                 6           4     -2              2
```

I am trying to see whether students' predictions are accurate and to what degree. To do this, I am thinking of performing a t-test on the difference between anticipated score and actual score, but I am not sure whether to use the raw difference or the absolute change. Which one would be more appropriate and in what cases?

When conducting a t-test, if using the absolute change the difference is significantly different than 0 (1.2+-0.6), but when using the actual raw change the 95% confidence interval is around 0 (+-1.1)

Which metric is more appropriate in this case? When would the other metric be more appropriate? I am trying to see if students' predictions are accurate and to what degree.

Thanks.

Comment: If your goal is to evaluate the accuracy of their predictions, you might want to try a measure of agreement/reliability. The t-test is evaluating a shift in the means - you could end up with a mean difference of 0 even if each individual participant changes their score by a very large amount.

Comment: @TPM Could you elaborate on what a good measure of agreement/reliability would be?

Comment: We would need to know more about your data. But a good place to start would be checking out measures like: Spearman's correlation, Fleiss kappa, Kendall's tau, intraclass correlations, and Krippendorff's alpha

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are

> trying to see whether students' predictions are accurate and to what
>   degree.

A t-test is not appropriate here.

You could look at the correlation between actual scores and predicted scores. You could look at the distribution of either absolute difference or raw difference (I suggest a box plot, a quantile normal plot and a strip plot).  You could see if the relationship between actual and predicted varies depending on how well they do (I suggest a Tukey mean difference plot, also known as a Bland Altman plot).

If you have other information about the students, then other things become possible.  E.g. Do boys predict differently from girls? In what ways?  But you didn't ask about that, so I won't expand on that.

Comment: Why is a t-test not appropriate?

Comment: Because you aren't comparing means, which is what a t-test does.

Comment: I do not understand. The questioner asked "I am trying to see whether students' predictions are accurate and to what degree." That seems to me to be asking about means. Two sets of scores could correlate highly and yet be very different pairs of values.  Please explain your thinking: why is a t-test not appropriate?

Comment: Because the question isn't "is one mean higher than the other?" but "are the predictions accurate?"

Comment: A correlation will not tell the op whether the predictions are accurate, in an absolute sense, which is the question posed.  A t-test will address that question.  So, please explain your answer further.  Why is a t-test not appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You should use what you call the actual raw change based on the following reasoning.  If the null hypothesis of no difference (other than due to chance) is true, there will still be some amount of difference between the actual and anticipated score - due to chance.  Some scores will differ on the positive side, some on the negative side, and the average of the difference scores is expected to be zero.  If you take the absolute value of the difference scores, all non-zero differences will be positive.  The expected value of the absolute value of the difference scores will not be zero and you may well find statistical significance when the mean of the absolute difference scores is compared to zero.  I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you expand on when I would choose one over the other?

Comment: @Grint  Do you have any thoughts on why or when the absolute value would be analyzed?  For example, what question would you be trying to answer with that analysis?

Comment: I guess when using the raw value I am testing whether their predictions are biased in a particular direction, and using the absolute would be for when I wish to test if predictions are incorrect in any direction? The problem is, wouldn't using the absolute almost always yield a "significant" p-value? For example, if I randomly generate 100 "differences" using rnorm(100,0,0.01) which is centered around 0 with very low variance (say scores can range from 1 to 10), you are almost guaranteed to get a "significant" p-value even if the difference is marginal. Should I be looking at CIs here?

Comment: @Grint Yes, using absolute value will often result in statistical significance even if the null hypothesis of no difference is true.  I cannot think of any situation where using the absolute value would make sense.  Perhaps others can think of some.