# Relative changes instead absolute values in LSTM training

Tags: time-series, lstm

I am reading some papers about glucose time series prediction and I have noticed that some of them propose LSTM models that use relative changes between two measures.
For example, if $$ glucose(t)=60, glucose(t+1)=65$$ We will send $$\triangle_{t}=5$$ to the next cell. If this cell were the last one, we would calculate the absolute value and return it.

Does this approach have any advantage or is it only a way of representation?

Article:

K. Li, J. Daniels, C. Liu, P. Herrero and P. Georgiou, "Convolutional Recurrent Neural Networks for Glucose Prediction," in IEEE Journal of Biomedical and Health Informatics, vol. 24, no. 2, pp. 603-613, Feb. 2020, doi: 10.1109/JBHI.2019.2908488.

Comment: This may be related to change scores (I know there are other posts on this, but I don't see them quickly) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359359/when-to-use-raw-not-relative-change-vs-absolute-change-in-a-t-test